# How to mock the custom util class

Tags: mockito

How can I mock the custom util class? I am getting the error below:

```
[ERROR] 2019-08-20 12:06:02:197 [] com.metlife.api.clientlibrary.util.JWSRequestUtil.prepareRequestJWS():71 - Exception in preparing JWS request :: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

The code is:

```
public class EPartnerPromotionHelperTest {
    @InjectMocks
    EPartnerPromotionHelper ePartnerPromotionHelper;

    @Mock
    private  JWSRequestUtil jwsRequestUtil;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSavePromotion() throws Exception {

        String loggerId = "loggerId";
        PromotionDTO promotionDTO = new PromotionDTO();
        promotionDTO.setDescription("description");
        promotionDTO.setCreationDate(new Date());
        promotionDTO.setModifiedDate(new Date());

        Mockito.when(jwsRequestUtil.prepareRequestJWS(Matchers.any(EPartnerRestRequestDTO.class)
                ,Matchers.any(Boolean.class))).thenReturn("test");

        PromotionDTO response =ePartnerPromotionHelper.savePromotion(loggerId,promotionDTO);
        assertNotNull(response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the error message comes from the invocation of your `prepareRequestJWS` method, you can change your syntax and use [`doReturn`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doReturn-java.lang.Object-) instead.

```
Mockito.doReturn("test")
       .when(jwsRequestUtil)
       .prepareRequestJWS(Matchers.any(EPartnerRestRequestDTO.class), 
                          Matchers.any(Boolean.class));
```

Writing it like this the `prepareRequestJWS` method won't be invoked, check the `Overriding a previous exception-stubbing` part that is described in the javadoc of the `doReturn` method. This also applies to normal methods that would throw Exception's when they are invoked.

However a question would be why this exception is coming from your `JwsRequestUtil` class in the first place. Feel free to add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: Still i'm getting the same error.Actually prepareRequestJWS() is static method in util class . Also i cant use PowerMockito.                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                              
       public static java.lang.String prepareRequestJWS(java.lang.Object type, boolean encrypted);  any idea on it?

Comment: If its a `static` method `Mockito` can not `mock` it. That might fail silently and your real method is invoked. If you post your method maybe we can figure out a way to get you your desired result by mocking the parameters instead. Else your only option is to change the method to `non static` or to introduce another dependency which makes the call to the `static` method.